# Contact form 7 set minimum field value

Tags: forms, wordpress, contact-form

I want set a minimum value in "Amount" field.  An error message should be lower than the minimum value.

```
<p>Amount:<br />
  [text* amount]</p>


<p>Name :<br />
    [text* your-name] </p>

<p>Email :<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>

<p>Message :<br />
    [textarea your-message] </p>


<p>[submit "SEND"]</p>
```

Comment: Did the `number` input not work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact Form 7 has a [number field](http://contactform7.com/number-fields/). So, in your case, you could do something like:

```
[number* amount min:10 max:99 step:1 "40"]
```